# Получение данных с помощью API hh.ru

Tags: python, requests, hh.ru-api

Помогите пожалуйста те, кто работал с API hh.ru. Мне нужно по определенной профессии получить количество вакансий в России (если это возможно). В API копался, ничего подобного не нашел. Те, кто знает, помогите пожалуйста.